# Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в docker-compose конфиге

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, делаю тут задание одно, docker-compose ругается на отсутствие доветочий в строке "maria_db:". Ошибка: yaml: line 17: could not find expected ':', можете подсказать, в чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: прикрепите, пожалуйста, код ошибки текстом с использованием форматирования - это улучшает индексируемость вопроса в поисковиках

Answer (score 0):

Засунул config в yaml линтер, были скрытые символы.